# Does a lifted functor on $\mathbf{1Met}$ preserve isometries?

Tags: ct.category-theory, metric-spaces, isometries

Let $\mathbf{1Met}$ denote the category of metric spaces with distance bounded by $1$ and nonexpansive maps ($1$-Lipschitz functions). I call isometry a distance-preserving map (some people require it is a bijection, I don't). Let $F: \mathbf{Set} \rightarrow \mathbf{Set}$ be a functor on $\mathbf{Set}$ that preserves monomorphism (i.e. if $f$ is injective, then $F(f)$ is injective), and let $\widehat{F}: \mathbf{1Met} \to \mathbf{1Met}$ be a lifting of $F$ along the evident forgetful functor $U: \mathbf{1Met} \to \mathbf{Set}$ (i.e. $U\widehat{F} = FU$).

Does $\widehat{F}$ preserve isometries? I have not been able to prove this, nor find a counterexample.

Optional restricitions: in my research I am considering $F$ to be the $n$-ary product functor in $\mathbf{Set}$ ($X \mapsto X^n$). I am also considering other categories that look like $\mathbf{1Met}$, like $1$-bounded pseudometrics, quasimetrics, metametrics, etc., so it would be great if the proof (supposing it exists) does not rely on the properties of metric spaces. The most general category I need has objects $(A,d)$ where $A$ is a set and $d:A \times A \rightarrow [0,1]$ (I call these fuzzy relations) and morphisms are nonexpansive map (i.e. $d_B(f(a),f(a'))\leq d_A(a,a')$).